# Convert scroll position to a variable value between 0 and 3

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to reproduce something similar to this tunnel effect [here](https://digitaloriginal.app/).

I need to convert scroll position to a value which start from 0 and and ends to 3.
This will happen every 100vh on a different item, starting on each from 0 to 3 in an interval of 100vh.

My function right now looks like this, but the calculations look incorrect.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    $('.img-container').each(function(i, el) {
       var start = h*i;
       var end = start + h;
       if (scr >= start && scr < end) {

         var percZ = (scr-start)*3/((scr-start)+h);
         $(el).css('transform', 'scale('+percZ+')');

         if (percZ > 3) {
           $(el).css('transform', 'scale(3)');
         }
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you expect the order of operations to be here regarding this line `var percZ = (scr-start)*3/((scr-start)+h);` regarding the multiplication and division. As its written the multiplication is done first (left to right), but it would seem that you would want the division to go first?

Comment: @GetSet doesn't seem to make any difference - added `console.log((scr-start)*(3/((scr-start)+h)), ((scr-start)*3)/((scr-start)+h))` to OPs code

Comment: "doesn't seem to make any difference" ... I didn't suggest that you arbitrarily switch the two, but rather I commented to gauge your understanding of the math expression. From your response it appears you are confused on the math. Could you explain in plain words how you want the formula to work? That is, how does (ideally) the value get into the range of 0 to 3 (real number set, assuming)?

Comment: Dont explain the math expression from your code which we know doesnt work. Explain your intent in plain words on how to arrive at the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved through a remap function which converts the scroll position in a value ranging from 0 to 3:

```
function createRemap(inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax) {
  return function remaper(x) {
      return (x - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
  };
}

var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
  var vh = Math.round(window.innerHeight / 100);
  var h = window.innerHeight;

  $('.img-container').each(function(i, el) {
    var start = h*i;
    var perc = createRemap(start, start + h, 0, 3); 
    if (scr >= start && scr < tunnelEnd) {
      
      $(el).css('transform', 'scale('+perc(scr)+')');

      if (perc(scr) > 3) {
        $(el).css('opacity', 0);
      }

    } else if (scr == 0) {
      $(el).css('opacity', 0);
    } 
  })
```